# How to add event listener to buttons in a loop

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to create a menu of buttons. In the menu, I want to add event listeners when I click a button. 
My problem is I'm not sure how to implement it, to make it possible to target each button with the specific code that button need to run.

I have a button that needs to turn red when clicked and another that needs to load another site. How is it possible to achieve these things.

At the moment I generate the Buttons from a JSON document and create them in the code you can see below.

EDIT: added id attribute to javascript

```
function createMenu(jsonObj) {
let menu = jsonObj["menuitems"];
console.log(menu[0]);

let table = document.createElement("table");

for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    let tableSection = document.createElement("tr");
    let tableItem = document.createElement("td");
    tableSection.appendChild(tableItem);
    let button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    tableItem.appendChild(button);
    let text = document.createTextNode(menu[i].item);
    button.appendChild(text);
    button.classList.add("menuButtons");
    table.appendChild(tableSection);
    button.setAttribute("id", menu[i].id);
    button.addEventListener("click",/*What do i write here*/);
}

document.getElementById("menuDiv").appendChild(table);
}
```

Comment: There's an example on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp. Have you tried this? If you have, what are you not understanding?

Comment: `I have a button that needs to turn red when clicked and another that needs to load another site.` how do you know what each button will do?

Comment: @controlAltDel please dont recommend w3schools. Its inaccurate.

Comment: @JonasW.I can see I didn't get the setAttribute method in the version I posted here. I think I can use that to identify each button. The buttons need to do different things, but not sure how I do that, from the code i have atm.

Answer (score 0):

Standards advice to not declare variable in loop. You can make an attribute (*data-horsSujet*) and compare the value to know what to do. Like this :

```
function createMenu(jsonObj) {
const menu = jsonObj["menuitems"];
console.log(menu[0]);

const table = document.createElement("table");

const myfct = function (event) {
    const button = event.target;
    if (button.getAttribute("data-horsSujet") == 1)
        button.style.color = "red";
    else
        document.location = "google.fr";
}

for (let i = 0, tableSection, tableItem, button, text; i < menu.length; i++) {
    tableSection = document.createElement("tr");
    tableItem = document.createElement("td");
    tableSection.appendChild(tableItem);
    button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    tableItem.appendChild(button);
    text = document.createTextNode(menu[i].item);
    button.appendChild(text);
    button.classList.add("menuButtons");
    table.appendChild(tableSection);
    button.setAttribute("id", menu[i].id);
    button.addEventListener("click", myfct);
    button.setAttribute("data-horsSujet", i);
}

document.getElementById("menuDiv").appendChild(table);
}
```